IS there anyway to create a interaction between chatbot using langchain
I have created a chatbot using langchain and openai embeddings which reads pdf and breaks down into chuncks to retrieve answers . now i have multiple similar context in the pdf but it gives the top one i want it to give a prompt if there are multiple answers is there any way .
right now i have a chat bot which replies only top 1 answer i tried this code
# Perform a similarity search using the vector store
relevant_contexts = vectorstore.similarity_search(question, k=2)  # Adjust 'k' for the number of results as needed
If multiple relevant answers are found, ask for clarification
    if len(relevant_contexts) > 1:
        clarification = "I found multiple references to your query. Could you specify which one you mean?"
        options = [ctx.page_content for ctx in relevant_contexts]  # Assuming `page_content` holds the relevant text
        define_logger(
            level=20,
            user=current_user,
            loggName=inspect.stack()[0],
            pid=os.getpid(),
            message=f"Ambiguous query detected: {question}",
            body={"question": question, "options": options, "clarification": clarification}
        )
        return {
        "clarification": clarification,
        "options": options
         }

this is not working as im expecting
